# executenonquery not working, no columns edited

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to update my database. However when I print object that gets returned by ExecuteNonQuery() it says 0.

Here's my code:

```
try
        {
            using(dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(dbConnString))
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                using(dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    dbCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE 'GameObject' SET 'LocationX' = @locX, 'LocationY' = @locY, 'LocationZ' = @locZ WHERE 'id' = @id";
                    dbCommand.Parameters.AddRange(new SqliteParameter[]
                    {
                        new SqliteParameter("@locX") { Value = x},
                        new SqliteParameter("@locY") { Value = y},
                        new SqliteParameter("@locZ") { Value = z},
                        new SqliteParameter("@id") {Value = id}

                    });
                    int i = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Debug.Log(i);
                }//end dbcommand
            }//end dbconnection
        }//end try
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e);
        }
```

I think it's because of my where clause, because when I add this clause to a select query, my variables won't get updated. I just can't find what's wrong with it.

select query:

```
try
        {
            using(dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(dbConnString))
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                using(dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM 'GameObject' WHERE 'id' = @id"; //without the where everything works fine
                    dbCommand.Parameters.Add (new SqliteParameter("@id") { Value = 1});
                    using(dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while(dbReader.Read())
                        {
                            id = dbReader.GetInt32(0);
                            x = dbReader.GetFloat(1);
                            y = dbReader.GetFloat(2);
                            z = dbReader.GetFloat(3);
                        }
                    }//end dbreader
                }//end dbcommand
            }//end dbconnection

            _object.transform.position = new Vector3(x,y,z);
            Debug.Log ("id: " + id + " location: " + _object.transform.position);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e);
        }
```

Comment: Is this query works on your database manager? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: sorry i meant that my variables don't get updated if i add the where to my select query. i'll post the code for my select too.

Comment: @SonerGönül no it doesn't work in the manager either. I don't understand because I only have 1 item in the database and its id is 1

Comment: @Aelion Put a breakpoint on your `int i = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` line, debug your code and tell what is your `dbCommand` exactly looks like.

Comment: @SonerGönül http://puu.sh/hCdD8/c509209a46.png

Comment: @SonerGönül Actually..if I put the query in my database manager without apostrophes, it does update my values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason might be from https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

> For resilience when confronted with historical SQL statements, SQLite
>   will **sometimes** bend the quoting rules above:
>
> If a keyword in single quotes (ex: `'key'` or `'glob'`) is used in a
>   context where an identifier is allowed but where a string literal is
>   not allowed, then the token is understood to be an identifier instead
>   of a string literal.

Since none of them is keyword, try to use them without single quotes.